# Excel VBA Shift Data to next available row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on an income/expense monitoring excel. I have a table which monitors the pending or outstanding transactions between the user and others.

The actual table in my spreadsheet is static, from B52:H66 only, regardless of how many data are inputted there.

For simplicity, say the table has only three columns: NAME, AMOUNT, and REMARKS. The REMARKS column has two option buttons in **each cell of the column**: () Pending and () Paid. The buttons are linked to the very cell it is placed on. Clicking () Paid will return a value of "1" while () Pending will return "2".

I made a macro button that when clicked will delete all rows with () Paid remarks. Clicking the button will also change the option button back to () Pending. However, I would like also, upon deleting the () Paid data, to shift whatever data is left upward to the first usable cell/row in the table.

For example: (For simplicity, say only 4 entries)

ROW 1: Ben --- $50 --- () Pending

ROW 2: Danny --- $100 --- () Paid

ROW 3: Fay --- $280 --- () Paid

ROW 4: Diane --- $80 --- () Pending

Click macro button ---> delete all () Paid entries ---> Result below

ROW 1: Ben --- $50 --- () Pending

ROW 2: Diane --- $80 --- () Pending

From the result, Diane shifted from ROW 4 to ROW 2 because ROW 2 and ROW 3 are now blanks and ROW 2 is next usable row.

I have no idea how to achieve this. I tried researching, but I can't seem to find the right code for this. Some sites suggests to delete the row and shift the cells up. But I cannot do that as other data in that row will also be deleted. I need to **just delete the input data but not the row itself**.

Please see screenshot of the table for your reference.

[image]

Any suggestions or references if you have encountered this? Thank you very much!

```
Sub OUTSTANDING()
If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
If Range("H52").Value = 1 Then
    Range("B52:G52").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("H52").Value = 2
End If
If Range("H53").Value = 1 Then
    Range("B53:G53").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("H53").Value = 2
End If
If Range("H54").Value = 1 Then
    Range("B54:G54").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("H54").Value = 2
End If
End Sub
```

Sincerely,

Fritze

Answer (score 0):

## using array

```
Sub test()
  Dim myRng As Range, i As Variant, j As Variant, n As Variant, ary As Variant

    Set myRng = Range("B25:H66")

    For i = 1 To myRng.Rows.Count
      If myRng.Cells(i, myRng.Columns.Count) <> 1 Then
        If Not IsArray(ary) Then
          ReDim ary(1 To myRng.Columns.Count, 1 To 1) As Variant
        Else
          ReDim Preserve ary(1 To UBound(ary, 1), 1 To UBound(ary, 2) + 1) As Variant
        End If

        For j = 1 To myRng.Columns.Count
          ary(j, UBound(ary, 2)) = myRng.Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
      End If
    Next i

    If Not IsArray(ary) Then
        With myRng
            .Resize(, myRng.Columns.Count - 1).Value = ""
            .Resize(, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count - 1).Value = 2
            Exit Sub
        End With
    Else
        If UBound(ary, 2) < myRng.Rows.Count Then
            n = UBound(ary, 2)
            ReDim Preserve ary(1 To UBound(ary, 1), 1 To myRng.Rows.Count) As Variant

            For j = n + 1 To myRng.Rows.Count
                ReDim Preserve ary(1 To UBound(ary, 1), 1 To j) As Variant

                For i = LBound(ary, 1) To UBound(ary, 1) - 1
                    ary(i, j) = ""
                Next i
                ary(UBound(ary, 1), j) = 2
            Next j
        End If
    End If

    myRng.Value = Application.Transpose(ary)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @PaichengWu I tried it in my spreadsheet, and it works. But the remaining data did not shift upward to the next usable row. Do you know any reference regarding this?

Comment: what if replace `range(myRng.cells(i,1), myRng.cells(i, myrng.columns.count-1)).clearcontents` with `range(myRng.cells(i,1), myRng.cells(i, myrng.columns.count-1)).delete xlshiftup`

Comment: Yes, i have researched that too. But the code delete the table or row itself. Is there any way I can just delete the input data, not the table / excel row itself? I can't delete the table as it will mess up other formula in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Why do you `Range("B53:G53").ClearContents` but keep `Range("H53").Value = 2`.  Should I clear `Range("H53")`?

Comment: The table is from B52:H66. Column H is the column with the option buttons. I only need to clear data from column B to column G. I have edited and attached a screenshot of the table for your reference. Thank you.

Comment: Cells in Column H are linked to the option buttons. If option button "Paid" is clicked, the cells in column H will return a value of 1 while value of 2 for the other option.

Answer (score 0):

assuming cells B24:H24 have headers of underlying cells, then you could use `Autofilter` and avoid looping

```
Sub test()
    With Range("B24:H66")
        .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="1"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete xlShiftUp
        End With
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @DisplayName thank you for this! Is there any way I can just delete the input data, not the table / excel row itself? I can't delete the table as it will mess up other formula in my spreadsheet.